# How to add a View to my MainWindow

Tags: .net, xaml, mvvm, binding

I'm trying to display a View in my MainWindow.

In the past, I've passed my View (of type UserControl) into my TabControl on my MainWindow and cast it to a TabItem and this works well.

In my new application, I'm not using a TabControl and sadly, this is the only way I knew how to insert a view into my MainWindow. I assume I can now use the ContentControl to display my View.

My issue is, I don't know how to bind my View to my `ContentControl`.

My XAML so far is pretty bare, it looks like

> ```
> <Window x:Class="BackUps.Logging.MainWindow"
>     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>     xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:BackUps.Logging"
>     Title="Logging Results" Height="350" Width="700">
>
> <Grid>
>     <Grid.Resources> 
>           <ContentControl 
>                    Content="{x:Type nameOfViewModel}"
>           />
>
>
>     </Grid.Resources>
> </Grid> </Window>
> ```

The above doesn't work and it seems as if my approach is wrong in that I'm technically hard coding it to only allow 1 View to ever be shown. However, just for my understanding, this is fine!

So, my 2 questions are:

1) What type does my View have to be (Window, Page or UserControl or will it work with any of these 3) 
2) How do I set up ContentControl to bind to my View?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your View should be of type `UserControl`.

In XAML you can use following code:

```
<Window x:Class="ContentBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ContentBinding"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <views:MyView x:Key="myView" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource myView}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Ah, I had it right, there was fault else where! Note to self, when learning, add a fixed visual control (like a button) so it shows on the screen even if the binding is poor in my ViewModel! D'oh! Thank you